# Java: why we need to extend a class when we can access the fields and methods from non sub class

Tags: java, inheritance

I am a bit confused about Inheritance. We extend a class so that its fields and methods are inherited by the sub class with the ultimate goal of being able to use those fields and methods in the sub class. But for a public class, we can access the fields and methods from a non sub class from wihin and outside the package also. Then what is the need to extend a class? We can also access private fields with the help of public getters and setters from non sub class (both from within and outside package).

Comment: That's not why you extend a class. Read about ploymorphism: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: If `SuperClass` has an instance field `value`, and `SuperClass` is instantiated, an instance of `SubClass` has no reference to the `value` of the `SuperClass` instance. I think that's what you think happens. It doesn't work like that. They will have two separate `value` fields.

Comment: Extending a class is often used in many cases when you want to create another class that already contains a bunch of methods and fields that you want in your new class, so you don't have to busy yourself with writing the code all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By extending class all methods and variable are inherited and you can  have your own copy to wich you can assign diff value and parameter